# Custom Post Type supports author

Tags: custom-post-types, user-roles, author, post-type-support

I am using 'author' in 'supports' array for my 'custom post type', that shows a list of all users of the site on add or edit post screen to assign author for the post. But I want to filter that list to a role. How can I filter authors list for a particular role? I don't want to show a long list of users there.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: When listing authors in a role, instead of displaying their names, display their posts?

Comment: no I have a custom post type that has 'author' support which displays authors names' as dropdown list on edit or add new post screen to choose from. I want to filter that list for a specific role e.g. admin so that only admin users will be on dropdown list of authors.

Comment: hmm your question appears to be incomplete, there was no mention of a drop down or user interface component to this question before that comment